# Description of /proc/driver/rtc output

Tags: bios, 22.10, rtc

I probably have a dead CMOS (BIOS main board?) battery. When I power on my computer the date and time is reverted to an old date (something like 2009-1-1).

So, I checked the following:

```
$ cat /proc/driver/rtc 
rtc_time    : 09:43:09
rtc_date    : 2023-03-23
alrm_time   : 08:34:43
alrm_date   : 2009-01-01
alarm_IRQ   : no
alrm_pending    : no
update IRQ enabled  : no
periodic IRQ enabled    : no
periodic IRQ frequency  : 1024
max user IRQ frequency  : 64
24hr        : yes
periodic_IRQ    : no
update_IRQ  : no
HPET_emulated   : yes
BCD     : yes
DST_enable  : no
periodic_freq   : 1024
batt_status : okay
```

Can somebody explain me what do these mean? I haven't found anything useful after googling it. Especially the fields `alrm_time` , `alrm_date`, and `batt_status`.

Comment: They seem very clear. Alarm Time, Alarm Date and Battery Status

Comment: I am 99 percent sure that `batt_status` is **not** "okay".

Comment: As soon as the machine starts up the battery gets some current so that is what is giving the okay status. The battery very well may not be holding a charge when the machine has no external power.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am suspecting also @David.  Anyway, I have to dig into the mainboard to find the battery. 